# JavaScript function not executing

Tags: php, javascript, forms, file

I need an extra set of eyes here.  I've been over this numerous times with no success.  The issue is the `getFilename` function, which as the name suggests, is supposed to get the file name of the uploaded file. No matter what I do, it doesn't seem to work, so I must be missing something.

```php
<?php
    $data = $_GET["data"];

    if($data)
    {
        echo '
            <head>
                <style>
                    .atklf
                    {
                        color: Red;
                        background: #292929;
                        border: 1px solid Red
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <iframe name="fuh1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
            <form
              action="attklstformupldproc.php"
              method="post"
              target="fuh1"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table border="2" cellpadding="3" frame="void" style="color: red; width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Priority:</td>
                        <td>Pirate: <span id="Pirreq"></span></td>
                        <td>Level:</td>
                        <td>Known Fleet Level:</td>
                        <td>X:</td>
                        <td>Y:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="Priority" class="atklf" name="Priority">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input id="Pirate" class="atklf" name="Pirate" type="text" size="17" /></td>
                        <td><input id="Level" class="atklf" name="Level" type="text" size="4" /></td>
                        <td><input id="Fleet_Level" class="atklf" name="Fleet_Level" type="text" size="4" /></td>
                        <td><input id="XCoord" class="atklf" name="XCoord" type="text" size="5" /></td>
                        <td><input id="YCoord" class="atklf" name="YCoord" type="text" size="5" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Outpost Level:</td>
                        <td>Known Wall Level:</td>
                        <td>Known Turret Level:</td>
                        <td colspan="2">Turret Types:</td>
                        <td>Group: <span id="Grpreq"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input id="Outpost_Level" class="atklf" name="Outpost_Level" type="text" size="4" /></td>
                        <td><input id="Knwn_wall_lvl" class="atklf" name="Knwn_wall_lvl" type="text" size="4" /></td>
                        <td><input id="Knwn_turr_lvl" class="atklf" name="Knwn_turr_lvl" type="text" size="4" /></td>
                        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><textarea id="Turret_Types" class="atklf" name="Turret_Types" rows="5" cols="16"></textarea></td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            <select id="Group" class="atklf" name="Group">
                                <option value="null">Pick a group</option>
                                <option value="General">General</option>
                                <option value="Sector 23">Sector 23</option>
                                <option value="Max Chaos">Max Chaos</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Base Picture:</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><input id="Base_Picture" name="uploaded_bp" class="atklf" type="file" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">Notes:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="1" colspan="6"><textarea id="Notes" class="atklf" name="Notes" rows="7" cols="60"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input id="hlfsubmit" class="atklf" name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" style="width: 90px;" onClick="assignVars()" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <input type="button" class="atklf" value="Reset debug" onClick="resetDebug()"/>
                    <input type="button" class="normal" value="Get File name" onClick="getFilename1()"/>
                </table>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function resetDebug() {
                document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "";
            }

            function formFieldvalue(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id).value;
            }

            function getFilename1() {
                document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = formFieldvalue("Base_Picture");
            }

            Pri = "1";
            Pir = "null";
            Grp = "null";

            function assignVars () {
                Pri = document.getElementById("Priority").options[document.getElementById("Priority").selectedIndex].value;
                Pir = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Pirate"));
                if (formFieldvalue("Level")) {
                    Lvl = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Level"));
                }
                else {
                    Lvl = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("Fleet_Level")) {
                    Flv = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Fleet_Level"));
                }
                else {
                    Flv = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("XCoord")) {
                    XCd = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("XCoord"));
                }
                else {
                    XCd = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("YCoord")) {
                    YCd = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("YCoord"));
                }
                else {
                    YCd = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("Notes")) {
                    Nts = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Notes"));
                }
                else {
                    Nts = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("Outpost_Level")) {
                    Opl = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Outpost_Level"));
                }
                else {
                    Opl = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("Knwn_wall_lvl")) {
                    Kwl = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Knwn_wall_lvl"));
                }
                else {
                    Kwl = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("Knwn_turr_lvl")) {
                    Ktl = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Knwn_turr_lvl"));
                }
                else {
                    Ktl = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                if (formFieldvalue("Turret_Types")) {
                    Tty = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Turret_Types"));
                }
                else {
                    Tty = encodeURIComponent("?");
                }
                Grp = encodeURIComponent(formFieldvalue("Group"));
                insertAttacktablerow();
                }

                if ( window.addEventListener ) {
                    window.addEventListener( "load", insertAttacktablerow, false );
                }
                else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
                    window.attachEvent( "onload", insertAttacktablerow );
                }
                function insertAttacktablerow() {
                    if (Pir != "null" && Grp != "null") {
                        document.getElementById("Pirreq").innerHTML = "";
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        else { // code for IE6, IE5
                            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                                //updateAttacktable();
                                document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }
                        }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","/attacklist/attklstformproc.php?Pri=" + Pri + "&Pir=" + Pir + "&Lvl=" + Lvl + "&Flv=" + Flv + "&XCd=" + XCd + "&YCd=" + YCd + "&Nts=" + Nts + "&Opl=" + Opl + "&Kwl=" + Kwl + "&Ktl=" + Ktl + "&Tty=" + Tty + "&Grp=" + Grp + "&data=' . $data . '",true);
                        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        document.forms[0].reset();
                    }
                    else if (Pir == "null") {
                        document.getElementById("Pirreq").innerHTML = "(<b>required</b>)";
                        document.getElementById("Pirreq").style.color = "red";
                    }
                    else if (Grp == "null") {
                        document.getElementById("Grpreq").innerHTML = "(<b>required</b>)";
                        document.getElementById("Grpreq").style.color = "red";
                    }
                }

            </script>
            <span id="debug1"></span>';

        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Restricted access.';
        }
```

Comment: You can use this structure in PHP: `<? if($foo) { ?> html code <? } ?>`. That will save a lot of headaches.

Comment: Where is the `formFieldvalue` function defined? PS: everyone reading this code will need an extra set of eyes.

Comment: @Salman, about halfway down the code

Comment: Choosing `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Water lilies.jpg` seems to return `Water lilies.jpg` in FF, `C:\fakepath\Water lilies.jpg` in Chrome/IE.

Comment: **Note**: you should check your HTML, you have some INPUT elements between a TR and a TABLE closing tags. (And a personal comment, the code looks like something I would have seen 12 years ago. Usually, Javascript and HTML are in separate files so it is all easier to maintain.)

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I removed my last answer because I finally took the time to execute your code. As you have it, it works for me.

Here's what I suggest you do. Remove your HTML and JavaScript and place them in a stand alone html file and load it in your browser. Add the necessary tags to make it complete. (Also, you're missing a "body" tag, not that this is the source of your problem.)

Then test it. If it works, then your problem is coming from somewhere else not in the code you provided. Do you have header and footer code somewhere?

If it doesn't work, start removing HTML and JavaScript in portions until it does work. Use this to isolate the cause of your bug.

Good luck.

Comment: the `files` attribute seems to be HTML5 only... or am I wrong? I've never seen that in HTML4

Comment: No, not wrong. It's not his problem anyway. I was just stabbing in the dark. Functionally, his code works when I run it. I may delete this answer in a few moments ....

Comment: See the edit history to see what Yanick and I were talking about.